# How to concatenate a string to a list of strings

Tags: kdb

I have a list of string

```
b:"0"^-9$string til 500
```

How do I concatenate a string (say "abc" to each element of b) so that I would have a list of below:

```
"abc000000000"
"abc000000001"
"abc000000002"
"abc000000003"
"abc000000004"
"abc000000005"
.
.
"abc000000499"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use each-right adverb like below:

```
  q) "abc",/:b
```

Comment: followup question, how do I append at the end at the same time, like "abc000000000xyz", "abc000000001xyz"....

Comment: ```q) "abc",/:b,\:"xyz"```
https://code.kx.com/q/ref/adverbs/#each-left